# Why is current working directory in vim different from where vim was started?

Tags: vim

vim is showing a different current working directory than the one I started vim with from the command-line.  The problem goes away if I run without my `.vimrc` (`vim -u NONE`).  How can I debug this to figure out why this is happening?

```
$ pwd
/Users/rbednark/Dropbox/git/quizme_personal_files/bin
$ vim --noplugin
:pwd 
/Users/rbednark/Dropbox/git/quizme_personal_files/bin
:edit settings.sh
:pwd 
/Users/rbednark/quizme-read-only-prod
(expected: 
  /Users/rbednark/Dropbox/git/quizme_personal_files/bin
 actual: 
  /Users/rbednark/quizme-read-only-prod
)
```

The problem goes away if I don't use my `.vimrc`:

```
$ vim -u NONE
```

Notes:

- `:set autochdir?` outputs `noautochdir`
- `:verbose set autochdir?` outputs `noautochdir`
- `:!pwd` and `:pwd` both output the same directory
- The problem also occurs with `vim --noplugin`
- I **have** recently upgraded `vim` and `python` (via `brew upgrade`).
- I have **not** changed my `.vimrc` lately (other than adding some comments).  It's under version control in git, so I confirmed these have been the only changes.
- I **have** installed and updated my plugins with vundle (`:VundleInstall` and `:VundleUpdate`).
- I **have** made some changes to my `.bashrc` but nothing that I think would change vim behavior.
- OS: *macOS Mojave 10.14.6*
- vim: *8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 20 2020 22:44:15) Compiled by Homebrew*

**EDIT:** I initially thought this was due to doing `:edit other-file`, but now I see it with just editing a single file, so I changed the above to remove that unnecessary aspect.

Comment: Does it happen if you start vim with `vim --noplugin`?

Comment: `:set autochdir?`

Comment: Yes, it also happens with `vim --noplugin` @jingx

Comment: `:set autochdir?` outputs `noautochdir` @Matt

Comment: Well if it goes away when you skip .vimrc, just pick that apart I guess...

Comment: Thanks @jingx, doing that led me to the problem and the solution!  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**: I had done an `:lcd` at some point, and my `.vimrc` has `autocmd`s to `mkview` and `loadview` when leaving and entering a buffer, so editing the file again was doing an `:lcd` to the other directory.

**Solutions:**

***option 1*** -- change the current working directory to the directory of the file being edited, and save:

```
cd %:p:h
:wq
```

***option 2*** -- remove the corresponding view file, e.g.,

```
$ rm ~/.vim/view/*myfile*
```

**How I solved / debugged:**
I bisected my `.vimrc` file to determine the offending line,
which was:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * silent! loadview
```

That indicated it was due to a view that was getting loaded.  I then viewed the corresponding `view` file in `~/.vim/view` and searched for the directory name, which yielded this line:

```
lcd ~/quizme-read-only-prod
```

See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11903/working-directory-different-than-current-file-directory

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet to save the fold state, while I am using `auto-session` to save my neovim session for each specific directory.

```lua
-- auto save fold view after exit a file
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufLeave", "BufWinLeave", "InsertLeave" }, {
    group = augroup("remenber_folds"),
    callback = function()
        vim.cmd("silent! mkview")
    end,
    group = general,
    desc = "save fold view",
})

-- auto load fold view after enter a file
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "BufRead", "BufWinEnter", "BufEnter", "FocusGained" }, {
-- vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufWinEnter"}, {
    group = augroup("remenber_folds"),
    callback = function()
        vim.cmd("silent! loadview")
    end,
    group = general,
    desc = "load fold view",
})
```

And adding `vim.cmd [[set viewoptions-=curdir]]` to my `options.lua` file perfectly solves the problem, I can automatically save the session and fold state after I leave a buffer or quit neovim, and load them when entering the buffer or opening neovim at the same dir.